# Using shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Previous Windows user here,

I have "shortcut" keys on my laptop's keyboard (Toshiba) such for Volume Up/down, Brightness Up/down, Pause Media, Skip media, etc. They are on the same keys as the function keys.

Now to turn the volume up, I have to press `Fn` + `F10` (volume up) instead of just `F10` (like in Windows).

How do I change it so that I can simply press the key (without `Fn`) to run these shortcuts?

Comment: Refer to your laptop manual. There should be Fn-Lock feature. It is either a button on your keyboard, some key combination, like Fn+ESC, or a BIOS setting. This is not controlled by an OS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Tried `Fn` + `Esc`, no luck.

Comment: It depends on the laptop make and model. It is not about trying for luck. Just look into the manual and see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The setting about what is activated directly (media keys or function keys) or after hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd> is not determined by the software, but by your hardware. Depending on the brand of your laptop, you may be able to change the behavior on the fly with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Depending on your laptop, that change may stick or not. To have the setting stick, the laptop may provide an option in the BIOS.

So, bottom line, this depends on your specific laptop hardware and needs to be controlled through it.